# Android studio not showing navigation bar

Tags: java

In MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.myanimal

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAnimalTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MyAnimalTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

In Navbar.java:

```
package com.example.myanimal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class NavBar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        // Set up the top-level destinations in the navigation graph
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder( R.id.destination_home, R.id.destination_profile)
.build();

        // Connect the navigation controller to the bottom navigation view
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
    }
}
```

The above both codes are in the same directory. But in virtual screen, it shows "Hello, Android!" but the bottom navigation bar is not shown. How should i solve the problem?

I tried combining the content of NavBar.java into the MainActivity.kt, but the app is not working and wouldn't allow me to open the app.